# avoid latches in frequecny divider using fsm - Verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl, quartus

I am new to verilog and HDL.
I want to implement a N-frequency divider,
which count clock ticks (pos and neg) and start the counting mechanism from the first rising edge of the input clk.
In addition the clk divider has to support synchronous rst_n.

I am using Altera Quartus and the following code

```html
module clk_divider_fsm
(
 in_clk,
 rst_n,
 out_clk
);

input in_clk, rst_n;
output out_clk;

parameter prescaler = 10;
parameter BIT_DEPTH = `CLOG2(prescaler);
parameter S0 = 2'b00, S1 = 2'b01, S2 = 2'b10;
parameter CNT_RESET = {BIT_DEPTH{1'b0}};
//parameter CNT_FIRST = {BIT_DEPTH-1{1'b0}, 1'b1};
reg [1:0] ps, ns;
reg out_change;
reg out;
reg [BIT_DEPTH:0] cnt;

initial
begin
 ps = S0;
 ns = S0;
 cnt = CNT_RESET;
 out_change = 1'b0;
 out = 1'b0;
end

always @ (in_clk)
begin
 if(!rst_n)
  ps = S0;
 else
  ps =  ns;
// begin
//  if(ns != ps)
//   ps =  ns;
// end
end

always @ (in_clk)
begin
 case(ps)
  S0: begin
   if(in_clk === 1'b1)
   begin
    out_change <= 1'b1;
    ns <= S1;
    cnt <= CNT_RESET + 1'b1;
   end
   else
   begin
    out_change <= 1'b0;
    cnt <= CNT_RESET;
    ns <= S0;
   end
  end
  S1: begin
   if(in_clk === 1'b0)
   begin
    if(cnt == prescaler)
    begin
     cnt <= CNT_RESET + 1'b1;
     out_change <= 1'b1;
     ns <= S2;
    end
    else
    begin
     cnt <= cnt + 1'b1;
     out_change <= 1'b0;
     ns <= S2;
    end
   end
   else
   begin
    out_change = 1'b0;
    ns = S1;
    cnt <= cnt;
   end
  end
  
  S2: begin
   if(in_clk == 1'b1)
   begin
    if(cnt == prescaler)
    begin
     cnt <= CNT_RESET + 1'b1;
     out_change <= 1'b1;
     ns <= S1;
    end
    else
    begin
     cnt <= cnt + 1'b1;
     out_change <= 1'b0;
     ns <= S1;
    end
   end
   else
   begin
    out_change = 1'b0;
    ns = S2;
    cnt <= cnt;
   end
  end
  default: begin
   out_change <= 1'b0;
   cnt <= CNT_RESET;
   ns <= S0;
  end
 endcase
 
 if(!rst_n)
 begin
  ns <= S0;
  cnt <= CNT_RESET;
 end
end

always @ (posedge out_change or negedge rst_n)
begin
 if(!rst_n)
  out <= 1'b0;
 else
  out <= ~out;
end


assign out_clk = (prescaler == 1) ? (in_clk & rst_n) : out;

endmodule
```

After synthesis I get warnings about latches used for cnt register.
What am I doing wrong?

Can you guide me with good practice tips to avoid such cases in the future or more elegant ways to implement those kind of RTL?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
always @ (in_clk)
...
always @ (posedge out_change or negedge rst_n)
```

If you want to be synchronous you can't do that. You have to change values on the same posedge of in_clk.
But in general, we use PLL/DCM to divide clock. Clock follow special routing in FPGA using specials buffers.

[edit]

```
always @ (in_clk)
```

This will synthesize latches. If you don't want latch (and be synchronous) you have to trigger all your process (always@) with the same **posedge** of clock. In your case with the same posedge of in_clk :

```
always @ (posedge in_clk)
```

See [Synthesizing Latches](https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/verilog_designers_guide/synthesizing_latches/)

Comment: thank you for your answer. I am trying to implement a simple clock divider for learning purposes. Why there are latches using the design above?

Comment: There are latches because you are not fully synchronous.

Comment: The latches are used for cnt register not for out nor out_change registers. Why out_change mechanism is affecting the state machine counter?

Comment: You have to trigger on posedge of clk.